# Do I have to listen for server output while sending data to an SMTP server?

Tags: windows, email, sockets, smtp

I have problems implementing SMTP protocol over WinSock API. Here's what I do now. The client creates a non-blocking socket, connects to the server and exchanges data with it.

It uses "send string" primitive which efectively calls `send()` in a loop until the whole string is transmitted and "receive string" primitive which calls `recv()` in a loop until a string ending with CRLF is accumulated or timeout occurs.

The above dumb approach works, except on one specific server deployed at the customer's site. On this server the client sends `EHLO`, `AUTH`, `MAIL FROM`, `RCPT`, `DATA`, each time receiving a reasonable responce. Then it sends the mail message body line-by-line (not trying to receive anything from the server) and after some time `send()` (several hundred lines sent) stars returning `WSAEWOULDBLOCK`.

How do I handle this? Do I have to check for pending input on the socket after each line? Or what else should I do to predict and possibly prevent this situation?

Comment: Have you looked at the mail that is being sent (on the receiving end)? WSAEWOULDBLOCK is a non-fatal error. It might be as simple as re-trying the same line after the error.

Comment: Have you considered letting MS do this work for you? Using CDO, or MAPI, or one of the others?

Comment: @Justin Niessner: We do retry in a loop until either some long time elapses or the data is actually sent.

Comment: @bmargulies: No, we won't use any of those, that's our decision.

Comment: Then I recommend reading some open source code for this purpose to see if it's got something you are missing.

Comment: Could you use nonblocking sockets instead?

Or sleep after you receive this error message. You might be sending data much faster than the other side can handle it.

Comment: @barrycarter: I already use non-blockign socket and already loop and sleep if that code is returned. The problem is the code is returned repeatedly for about a minute.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668.aspx#winsock.wsaewouldblock_2):

> This error is returned from operations on nonblocking sockets that cannot be completed immediately, for example recv when no data is queued to be read from the socket. It is a nonfatal error, and the operation should be retried later.